# Change Data frame with the respective column names (conditionally) in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame named *products* as follows:

```
Credit | Savings | Premium
1        0         1
0        1         1
1        1         0
```

All the column values are String

I want to convert it into

```
Credit | Savings | Premium
Credit   0         Premium
0        Savings   Premium
Credit   Savings   0
```

in Spark?

Am using Spark 1.6.2 in Zeppelin.

Comment: As pointed out by @RamPrasad Tried this `val udf1 = udf {(presence: String) => 
  if(presence == "1") "Credit" else "0"
}`. It worked! Now am trying to create a single udf for all the columns by passing an additional parameter to the udf function like this `val udf1 = udf {(presence: String, product:String) => 
  if(presence == "1") product else "0"
} df.withColumn("Credit", udf1(sanderProdSmall("Credit"),"Credit"))` The error is found   : String("ind_cco_fin_ult2")
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that `Credit , Savings , Premium` are string columns

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ // for `when`

df : DataFrame = ..... 

df.replace("Credit", ImmutableMap.of("1", "Credit"))
.replace("Savings ", ImmutableMap.of("1", "Savings "))
.replace("Premium", ImmutableMap.of("1", "Premium"));
```

other wise you can also do like this...

```
df.withColumn("Credit", udf1)
.withColumn("Savings ", udf2)
.withColumn("Premium", udf3)
```

where udf1, 2, 3 are spark udfs to convert "1" to corresponding column names...

instead of udf.  you can use `when(cond, val).otherwise(val)` syntax as well.

```
 df.withColumn("Credit", when (df("Credit") === "1", lit("Credit")).otherwise(0)
 .withColumn("Savings", when (df("Savings") === "1", lit("Savings ")).otherwise(0)
.withColumn("Premium", when (df("Premium") === "1", "Premium").otherwise(0)
```

That's all.. Good luck:-)

Comment: Hey @RamPrasad Thank you so much for pointing out at udfs. Tried this `code`val udf1 = udf {(presence: String) => 
  if(presence == "1") "Credit" else "0"
}`code`

Comment: Am trying to create a single udf for all the columns by passing an additional parameter to the udf function like this `val udf1 = udf {(presence: String, product:String) => 
  if(presence == "1") product else "0"
}. But when I try to call this udf by running df.withColumn("Credit", udf1(sanderProdSmall("Credit"),"Credit"))` The error is found   : String("ind_cco_fin_ult2")
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column

Comment: yes udf 1 2 3 is just example. you can create single udf. where ever string you are using you can use  like `lit("Credit"), lit("Savings"), lit("Premium") ` `lit` is string column of Columntype since its expecting column type.

Comment: Awesome ! Worked ! Thank you Ram @RamPrasad !!

Comment: updated my answer with when otherwise as well. pls check!